# How can a polymorphic virus decrypt and execute portions of the code during runtime?

Tags: malware

I found [this](http://www.welivesecurity.com/2014/12/22/win32virlock-first-self-reproducing-ransomware-also-shape-shifter/) article about a polymorphic virus that encrypted and decrypted itself during runtime. The article said that the only non-encrypted part was a stub that decrypted the next part of the virus. How can it run code that was encrypted and then decrypted? The virus wasn't written in an interpreted language.

Comment: If machine code is not interpreted then how is it executed?

Comment: @techraf I suppose that's true. Does that mean the virus was written in assembly, instead of a higher-level language?

Comment: @Fluffy Not necessarily, and unlikely. The instructions to decrypt and run the machine code were likely written this way, however. It's job is essentially to unpack the encrypted part, decrypt it, and move into it.

Answer (score 1):

I have not developed a polymorphic virus myself but the idea of encrypting part of any executable (ELF, PE or otherwise) is not that unimaginable to me.

As long as there is a part of code that are non-encrypted to kick start the process (the stub in your description), it should work.
Remember that (while not encrypted, but instead compressed), the Linux kernel do compress most part of the image and use an analogical mechanism to decompress the image during boot time too.

As long as the initial stub constitute plain executable instruction that the CPU understands, the code can always keep track of the memory address, instruction pointer (EIP).

All the code needs to be sure is that before the EIP reaches the address of the instructions to be executed, the content (instructions) at those address are decrypted.  Similarly, the code logic has to be sure not to dereference any address that points to an encrypted memory range (unless the purpose is to decrypt it).

Does that makes sense?

Comment: That makes sense. So, each module was written in , say c, and compiled. And then each compiled binary is included in the full virus as a buffer. Then, when that module is needed, that module is executed? How is it executed with dropping to disk? Does each module need to be tailored in a certain way?

Comment: I don't know the detail of the virus you are talking about.  But it may not even need to be written as separate module (although that won't hurt either).  I believe in each of the executable format like ELF or PE, there are sections, which I think you can place each part of the code in different section of the file. These sections can be mapped to different memory pages.  Later you can move them around in memory after they are decrypted.  That is one way I can think off (not the only way).